# While Loop Construction

Tags: java, while-loop

Can you pls explain? I looked at this site for the data

http://www.d.umn.edu/~gshute/java/statements.html

```
while (boolean-expression) {
    nested-statements
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Explain what? What do you specifically not understand?

Comment: What the while loop does? What does boolean-expression mean?

Comment: you Sir need some serious tutorial-ing and google-ing to do

Comment: (1) It executes the nested statements until the boolean-expression turns false.  (2) If you ask trivial questions, you are not likely to get the answer/response which you want.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: I don't know how to ask questions. Each time it gets deleted. Very frustrated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "boolean-expression" is an expression that returns a boolean value (`true` or `false`). The term "nested-statements" refers to the statement(s) inside the while-loop.

For instance:

```
int x = 10;
while (x > 0) { // x > 0 is an expression with a boolean result
   System.out.println(x); // nested statement 1
   x--;                   // nested statement 2
}
```

(This will print 10, 9 .. 1 to the console).

Comment: tank you for assistance.